# How to check the bootnodes configured in my node

Tags: go-ethereum

Sorry if it's a very basic question, but I can't find it. I'm configuring a regular node in a private quorum network using geth. The node is not synchronizing and I'd like to check the bootnodes configured in the node. How can I get them?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a way to find it via command line directly.

However, when launching the node, you migth have the bootnode address indicated:

For example:

```
geth --a buch --of parameters --bootnodes **'BOOTNODEADDRESS'**
```